# Online/Offline events‎ work on Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: html, angular, google-chrome, firefox, rxjs5

I am developing an Angular 5 Web App that uploads some files to the server and i need to stop and buffer the upload once the internet connection is down.

Following this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine#Example), you can find the Mozilla Firefox support for the navigator.online property that reflects the status of the internet connection.

Still, when i run the live [example](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/navigator.onLine.html) and i disable my network card, as recommended by the app *"Toggle your wifi on/off while viewing this page"*,  nothing happens. I changed to Chrome and it works perfectly. I am using Firefox 58 and Chrome 63.

I have seen some posts discussing the offline mode of Firefox that has to be manually set by the user following **settings > more > offline mode**. Per spec Firefox considers a Network Status as different from an Internet Connection Status. Still, it is confusing and unexpected behavior.

**My questions is: how can I implement a cross-browser light-weight mechanism that checks for internet connection ?**

Comment: The example page works for me on 59.

Comment: firefox 58 should work exactly as chrome does in that regard. the settings > more > offline mode is obsolete and only true for very old firefox versions prior to v41. so you should actually be able to make that work in the intended way.

however, the only thing i can come up with on the spot, to simulate the behaviour efficiently in an alternative way, would be to implement a websocket connection to your server and check for its disconnect events. thats not very lightweight, but would work as well.

Comment: @PatrickKelleter Actually, i am using the settings > more > offline mode switch to test my code and it works well that way. Still, i need to know how to do this more effectively. If no solution found i would consider your solution. Thanks for helping.