# Online/offline notification is not working with firefox throttleing offline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox

Used Firefox Version 122.0.1 (64-bit)

Used Chrome Version Version 121.0.6167.185 (Official Build) (64-bit)

The used code (within react functional component)

```
  const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(window.navigator.onLine);
  const [showOnlineNotification, setShowOnlineNotification] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleStatusChange = () => {
      setIsOnline(window.navigator.onLine);
      if (window.navigator.onLine) {
        setShowOnlineNotification(true);
        setTimeout(() => {
          setShowOnlineNotification(false);
        }, 2000);
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener('offline', handleStatusChange);
    window.addEventListener('online', handleStatusChange);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('online', handleStatusChange);
      window.removeEventListener('offline', handleStatusChange);
    };
  }, []);
```

I am getting notified for chrome ..while for firefox I am not getting any

I test the offline mode

> Network => throttling => offline

There is a previous question with the same problem but it was about older versions of Firefox

[Online/Offline events‎ work on Chrome but not in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48643760/online-offline-events-work-on-chrome-but-not-in-firefox)